# Transfer from one table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, sql-insert

I have a two tables called `code` and `codeTemporary`.

In the code table I will use

```
select Code from codeTemporary with (nolock)
EXCEPT
select Code from code with (nolock)
```

This difference is about 10 million.

The `codeTemporary` table has "Id(guid)","Code(string)","boxId(guid)"

The `code` table will have same Id,getdate,getdate,default guid,default guid, same Code, same boxId, 1.

```
insert into Code
select Id,GETDATE(),GETDATE(),'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000','00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
(
select Code from code with(nolock)
EXCEPT
select Code from codeTemporary with(nolock)
) as Code
,boxId,1 
from codeTemporary with(nolock)
where boxId='xxxxxx (guid)'
```

But that code didn't work:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

How can I transfer missing codes from `codeTemporary` to `code`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would phrase this as:

```
insert into code
select
    id,
    getdate(),
    getdate(),
    '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
    '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
    code
from codeTemporary ct
where 
    boxId = 'xxxxxx (guid)'
    and not exists (select 1 from code c where c.code = ct.code)
```

Note that it is a good practice to enumerate the columns for `insert`, like:

```
 insert into code(col1, col2, col3, ...)
 select ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
insert into Code ( . . . ) -- list the columns here
    select Id, GETDATE(), GETDATE(),
          '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
          '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
          tc.code
    from codeTemporary ct
    where not exists (select 1 
                      from code c
                      where c.code = ct.code
                     ) and
          ct.boxId ='xxxxxx (guid)'
```